# Using OLAP QUBE as a data source in a MVC 4 intranet project

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, olap, adomd.net

I'm wondering can I use OLAP views as a data source in a mvc 4 web project? iv'e tried to Google it but I might be searching at the wrong places but I am not finding any decent results.

I found a connection string at 
http://www.connectionstrings.com/olap-analysis-services/
but I cannot reference ADOMD.NET

has any one done this? or is this just madness and should never be used.

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot reference ADOMD.NET"? Do you get error messages? Which? Have you installed the Analysis Services client software on your computer?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot install  Analysis Services client software on yout WebServer, as an option you can include **Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.dll** in your project and set it's build property to *Copy If Newer*.

You can find it here C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\ADOMD.NET\100. On a computer, which has Analytical Services installed.

Than it comes a standard code:

```
public CellSet RunMDX(string mdx)
{
    _logger.Debug(" Running mdx: " + mdx);
    using (var mdConn = new AdomdConnection())
    {
        mdConn.ConnectionString = Config.olapConnString;
        mdConn.Open();

        AdomdCommand mdCommand = mdConn.CreateCommand();
        mdCommand.CommandText = mdx; // << MDX Query 

        // work with CellSet
        CellSet cs = mdCommand.ExecuteCellSet();

        return cs;` 
        }
}
```